# Replace subview with another, animating size change

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uikit

I have a container view that has one subview. I want to replace this subview with another view which has a different size than original, so the container should be resized as well. Here's what I'm trying to do

```
UIView *content = NEW_CONTENT;
content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.contentContainer layoutIfNeeded]; // the container view

// make the old content disappear first
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                     UIView *oldContent = [self.contentContainer.subviews firstObject];
                     oldContent.alpha = 0.0f;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // then replace it with a new content
                     [UIView transitionWithView:self.contentContainer
                                       duration:0.1
                                        options:0
                                     animations:^{
                                         [[self.contentContainer.subviews firstObject] removeFromSuperview];
                                         [self.contentContainer addSubview:content];
                                         [content autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

                                         [self.contentContainer layoutIfNeeded];
                                     }
                                     completion:^(BOOL finished) { // completion stuff}];
                 }];
```

Old content opacity animates properly, but the layout is changed without any animation. How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

//3 views(container,first,second) allocate in viewdidload

```
UIView *container=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 250, 300)];
container.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview: container];

UIView *first=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 50, 100, 100)];
first.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview: first];

UIView *second=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 150)];
second.backgroundColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
second.alpha=0;
[self.view addSubview: second];
```

//Animation Function with first view removed adn changing the frame of container and adding the second view

```
[UIView transitionWithView:first duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    first.alpha=0.0;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView transitionWithView:second duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
        container.frame=CGRectMake(50, 10, 100, 200);
        second.alpha=1.0;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}];
```

I think so u r trying this same scenario.it works perfectly in my case